# Find and remove text within a tag, but not the tag itself

Tags: jquery

Here's my code so far,

```
$('target').find('span:contains("ea.")').remove();
```

I would like it to remove the letters "ea." but instead it's removing the SPAN container that it's in, which also contains other text that I want to keep.

Any way to just remove "ea." and nothing else? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('target span').text(function(_,txt) {
    return txt.replace(/ea\./g, '');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4j3E/)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this -

```
 var span = $('target').find('span:contains("ea.")');
 span.text(span.text().replace('ea.',''));
```

Or

```
$('target').find('span:contains("ea.")').text(function(pXL,txt){
      return txt.replace('ea.','');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $('target').find('span:contains("ea.")').text();
$('target').find('span:contains("ea.")').text(text.replace('ea.', ''));
```